# Eclipse won't start to run Stanford karel

Tags: eclipse, logging, karel

I am a beginner in programming and I decided to take the Stanford online Intro to Programming Methodology course (cs106a). I followed the instructions and unzipped the Eclipse files onto my computer. When I tried to open it, it said "An error has occurred, see log file. " I am not sure how to fix this and I really want to learn this program. I searched other similar questions and only one was found and the suggested solution was to set environmental variables. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do that.

How can I get Eclipse running?

Answer (score 2):

There could be numerous possibilities.

But first start with these.

(1) Are you using a 32 or 64 bit computer? Then you must use the Eclipse that is designed for your system.

(2) Do you have JDK installed?  It's on Oracle website.

(3) Is your OS in good shape? As in did you or other programs mess around registry?

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am using a 64 bit computer, but the website only gave me one option for windows. This is the link [link](http://see.stanford.edu/see/materials/icspmcs106a/software.aspx). I tried downloading both jdk and jre from the oracle website. My OS should be in good shape. I just bought it a couple months ago and it hasn't given me any problems before. I didn't mess around with the registry.

Comment: Actually, I uninstalled jdk and realized that it was the problem. Now the program seems to be opening just fine. Although, I am not sure why or how jdk interfered with eclipse. I guess the important thing is that its finally working now. Thanks SndLt for your response.